# formatting date not assigning new data from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, date

I have table as below:

```
ID    DateColumn

1     3/7/2019 5:29:38 AM
2     3/8/2019 5:28:38 AM
3     3/7/2019 5:30:38 AM
4     3/7/2019 5:31:38 AM
```

Currently date column This is processed as string in json object while bind to the grid.
I need to sort this json object based on date. Hence i need to convert string to date.

I tried writing code as below :

```
getServiceResults() {

    this.serviceCheckService.getResults(Appconfig.PageSize, Appconfig.PageNo).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe((data) => {

    this.resultData = data; 
            this.resultData.forEach(x => x.DateColumn = x.datecolumn.replace(new Date(x.DateColumn))); 

      });
  }
```

but the above code is giving syntax error, how should i convert  each value in date column from string to date, then , how should i sort that column?

Comment: any error are you facing? did you checked with console.log?

Comment: yes complete screen is going white

Comment: in console it shows syntax error

Comment: what console errors are coming. can you post here?

Comment: is there a better way of doing this conversion and sort?

Comment: Can you show us the raw format of data. Is it JSON?

Comment: x => x.DateColumn = x.datecolumn how DateColumn and datecolumn both can be correct?

Comment: i will show raw format, but need some time , in other environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this line. no need to use of replace method.

```
this.resultData.forEach(x => x.DateColumn = new Date(x.DateColumn));
```

For Sorting data you can use below code:

```
resultData.sort((item1, item2) => { if(new Date(item1) < new Date(item2)) {return 1} else return -1;} )
```

Comment: how should i sort?

Comment: Edited my answer for sort. please check

Comment: thanks its worked, could you please let me know , how to filter before a particular date?

Comment: Its filtering other fields , but date field not filtering _this.downloadData.filter(x=>x.LogTime=== '3/11/2019 7:29:32 AM')

Answer (score 2):

Your date format is American (MM/DD/YYYY), so you can pass it directly in the constructor. (This is a terrible format, because half the world uses DD/MM and you can't always tell from looking. Can you not send it as ISO?)

Once you have an array of objects, each with a date property, do this...

```
myArray.sort((a,b) => a.dateColumn.getTime() - b.dateColumn.getTime())
```

Comment: thanks its worked, could you please let me know , how to filter before a particular date?

Comment: Its filtering other fields , but date field not filtering _this.downloadData.filter(x=>x.LogTime=== '3/11/2019 7:29:32 AM')

Answer (score 1):

Expecting that the date format is in `MM/DD/YYYY` you can convert all string format date to `Date` type and then can sort.

```ts
// Convert string date to Date type
this.resultData.forEach(_d => _d.DateColumn = new Date(_d.DateColumn));

// Sort column based on date
this.resultData.sort((a, b) => a.DateColumn.getTime() < b.DateColumn.getTime() ? 1 : -1);
```

Comment: thanks its worked, could you please let me know , how to filter before a particular date?

Comment: Its filtering other fields , but date field not filtering _this.downloadData.filter(x=>x.LogTime=== '3/11/2019 7:29:32 AM')